# Google Gravity feature in Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my project I would like to have a page with images and it should move as if acted upon by gravity effect similar to 'Google Gravity'.

The images should be thrown by touch effect by swipe or touch in mobiles and fall and collide with other images as is acted upon by gravity.

Please suggest a plugin or jQuery code to support the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the jQuery physics plugin

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryphysics/

or Box2d-js

http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/index2.html